# Find the mapping of the curve by linear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

The mapping of curve $y = x^2$ by linear transformation $w = 2iz + (1-i)$ is....

I have looked at my textbook to solve this problem and also searched some materials in internet, but I don't found any solution for this. 
This is a MCQ and the choice leads to $u$ and $v$ variables to use.

Comment: What do you mean by 'mapping of the curve by linear transformation'?

Comment: Transformed curve.

Comment: Visualise the transformed curve: http://1clickurls.com/e1G_yE5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the parabola $(1+v)^{2}=2(1-u)$. The transformed curve consists of the points $(1-2x^{2})+i(2x-1)$. Write $u=1-2x^{2}$ and $v=2x-1$. Use the second equation to solve for $x$. You get $x=\frac {v+1} 2$. Substitute this into the first equation to get a formula satisfied by $u$ and $v$. A little simplification gives $(1+v)^{2}=2(1-u)$.